# basic components not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm just starting my first react web app but my components are not rendering. even a simple h1 element directly in the app.js file is not rendering. it did, however, after deleting the Routes, so my best guess is that the problem lies somewhere there.
the code:

app.js

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify'
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'

const Home = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/Home'))


const App = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <h1>App</h1>
      <ToastContainer />
      <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={Home} />
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <h1>Home Page</h1>
    )
}

export default Home
```

sorry for this very beginner question. please keep in mind that this is my first react web app.

Comment: It should be <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />

Comment: Are you using the react script to start your development server? (yarn start or npm run start)

Comment: sam yes i am using npm start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React route accepts ReactElement not ReactNode, no need of exact also

```
  <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  </Routes>
```

Comment: thank you very much. this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the tutorial you are using uses the previous react-router API. Please, try this:

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useRouteMatch,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}
```